# Can I give the same font size for H1 and H2

Tags: html, css, font-size, w3c-validation

I am validating my code in w3c validator.

I get the following error :-

### Consider using the h1 element as a top-level heading only (all h1 elements are treated as top-level headings by many screen readers and other tools).

The problem is the the largest font size in my site is 18px . The text in slider and some headings in body use 18px font sizes.

Can I give the same font size for H1 and H2 and use H1 in slier and H2 for headings in body.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, from a technical point of view you can use whatever font size you like for whatever element you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use any Heading tags for text body, it should only be used for headings. It's about semantics.

H1 means it's a top-level heading. H2 will be sub to a H1 etc.

If you want to have bigger font you use CSS to change the size of your paragraphs or create classes that you can apply to any element that need larger fonts.

If you need a certain size in a slider or any other element, just attach a class to it and style the correct elements.

With that said... you can of course make anything any size you like, but then you better forget validation since it's bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

How you style individual tags such as headings and paragraph text (i.e., what size, weight, etc.) is really up to you.  What's important is the logic behind the application of those tags.  Think of your page like an outline and there will be a natural hierarchy that emerges in the content, leading the user from one piece of information to the next.

The validator recommendation **is** important.  @rahiil gave a good suggestion for using classes, but I think it was a bad recommendation to "forget the error in W3C validator." Well-formed, valid and semantic markup is good for a lot of reasons, but two very important ones are:

1. Accessibility:  People that can't actually see what is on the screen can better understand the content of the page if you give them context by basically providing a roadmap to your content through the use of appropriate tags.
2. SEO: Your page ranking is affected by how you write your markup.  While Google doesn't publish its exact algorithms for how it calculates PageRank, they do make it clear (in their videos, Webmaster Tools, etc.) that semantics matter and it's recommended that you use only **one** `<h1>` tag on your page.

If you want to emphasize something on your page for visual effect by making larger, use the recommendation provided by Rahiil and create a set of classes that you can apply to your text elements to style them in different sizes easily.

Answer (score 1):

What css you use is depends on you. You can use same font size as you need. Forget the error in W3C validator, it still wants `type="text/css"` for <style> tag.  You can also use `<div class="h1">`  and use font size for it. 
`div.h1 { 
font-size : 18px;
}`